# How to utilize AAD in GCM cipher using BouncyCastle lightweight API

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, aes-gcm

During encryption, adding AAD for MACing seems to simply use an `AEADParameters`. But I am unclear about where I can later get this piece of AAD.

I think [`processAADBytes`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/AEADBlockCipher.html#processAADBytes%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) is most likely what I am looking for. [`processAADBytes`](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/modes/AEADBlockCipher.html#processAADBytes%28byte[],%20int,%20int%29) says

> If the implementation supports it, this will be an online operation
>   and will not retain the associated data.

I have confusion on this. I have 2 potential interpretations of this methods:

1. This is an alternative way to pass in AAD during encryption (in addition to `AEADParameters`), and the AAD will not be stored with cipher text.
2. This is a method to verify AAD during decryption. The AAD (from somewhere else) needs to be fed here for MAC verification.

I had expected to find a method like `getAAD()`. So I guess this cipher does not store AAD with the cipher text at all, and simply provides MAC verification on the data we claim to be the AAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. This is an alternative way to pass in AAD during encryption (in addition to AEADParameters), and the AAD will not be stored with cipher text.

That's correct, in general the `AEADParameters` will be handled the same way as the data in `processAADBytes`. AAD may not always have to be provided in front <sup>*1</sup>, and it may contain a lot of data (even though it usually doesn't). That means `processAADBytes` is more flexible than `AEADParameters` because it allows streaming and doesn't require buffering all the AAD at the same time.

On the other hand, `AEADParameters` could be useful for backwards compatibility and possibly a more efficient/cleaner design.

> 2. This is a method to verify AAD during decryption. The AAD (from somewhere else) needs to be fed here for MAC verification.

Well, yes, that's generally the case, but you could use `AEADParameters` here alternatively as well.

So both are correct. And yes, you are required to make sure that the receiver of the message either receives (and/or is able to generate) the AAD.

---

<sup>*1</sup> EAX allows for AAD to provided at any time, GCM requires additional calculations (modular exponentiation!) if you do provide AAD after encryption/decryption has started. CCM requires all AAD upfront. If you can, you *should* provide all AAD before encryption/decryption.